# C#, EF code-first: Table-Per-Type (TPT) with partial FK in PK

Tags: c#, ef-code-first, table-per-type

I like to setup EF (6) code first with a table per type setup. The requirement is that part of the PK in one inherited abstract type (see "TrackedEntity") is a FK to another abstract type (see "Entity"). Is that possible? If so, how can I do this with fluent API?

**Model**:

```
public abstract class Entity { public Guid Id { get; set; } }
public abstract class TrackedEntity : Entity { public int Version { get; set; } }
```

**Configurations**:

```
public class EntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Entity>
{
    public EntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("Entity");
        this.HasKey(x => x.Id);
        this.Property(x => x.Id).IsRequired().HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);
    }
}
```

```
public class TrackedEntityConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<TrackedEntity>
{
    public TrackedEntityConfiguration()
    {
        this.ToTable("TrackedEntity");
        this.HasKey(y => new { y.Id, y.Version });
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you creating tables for abstract types? Create tables for your concrete types.

Comment: What went wrong when you tried it?

Comment: @ChrisPickford, since every entity will inherit from the Entity abstract class, I can trace back all different objects just by using a guid. So this guid should be unique for all kinds of objects

Comment: @AluanHaddad, the Version does not get included in the PK of TrackedEntity table and the inherited classes from TrackedEntity do not have a Version in their table

Comment: I see what you mean. Personally, I think you would do much better with an interface vs an abstract class for this sort of thing

Comment: I think I understand what you are trying to accomplish, but each table will need it's own primary key column, this can't exist in a separate table. I'd suggest reading up on inheritance in EF, e.g. here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/implementing-inheritance-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application